# Decoding the *.gwt.rpc file generated as per GWT's serialization policy

Tags: gwt, gwt-rpc

I'm trying to do a bit of background reading on GWT RPC serialization policy and found that GWT whitelists the serializable types in a *.gwt.rpc file post compilation.

The following is an excerpt of one such .gwt.rpc file generated in my application:

```
com.subex.rocforms.sample.client.gwt.demo.PriorityModel, true, true, true, true, com.subex.rocforms.sample.client.gwt.demo.PriorityModel/3885356691, 3885356691
com.subex.rocforms.sample.client.gwt.demo.TeamModel, true, true, true, true, com.subex.rocforms.sample.client.gwt.demo.TeamModel/3447853257, 3447853257
com.subex.rocforms.sample.client.gwt.demo.dayGroup.DayGroupDateModel, true, true, true, true, com.subex.rocforms.sample.client.gwt.demo.dayGroup.DayGroupDateModel/2876933254, 2876933254
[Lcom.subex.rocforms.sample.client.gwt.demo.dayGroup.DayGroupDateModel;, true, true, true, true, [Lcom.subex.rocforms.sample.client.gwt.demo.dayGroup.DayGroupDateModel;/2086898801, 2086898801
com.subex.rocforms.sample.client.gwt.demo.dayGroup.DayGroupMemberModel, true, true, true, true, com.subex.rocforms.sample.client.gwt.demo.dayGroup.DayGroupMemberModel/471099479, 471099479
[Lcom.subex.rocforms.sample.client.gwt.demo.dayGroup.DayGroupMemberModel;, true, true, true, true, [Lcom.subex.rocforms.sample.client.gwt.demo.dayGroup.DayGroupMemberModel;/2005061951, 2005061951
com.subex.rocforms.sample.client.gwt.demo.dayGroup.DayGroupModel, true, true, true, true, com.subex.rocforms.sample.client.gwt.demo.dayGroup.DayGroupModel/2207687264, 2207687264
com.subex.rocforms.sample.client.gwt.demo.dayGroup.TimeStringModel, true, true, true, true, com.subex.rocforms.sample.client.gwt.demo.dayGroup.TimeStringModel/335976723, 335976723
com.subex.rocforms.sample.client.gwt.demo.scheduleGrid.ComponentModel, true, true, true, true, com.subex.rocforms.sample.client.gwt.demo.scheduleGrid.ComponentModel/2493196280, 2493196280
[Lcom.subex.rocforms.sample.client.gwt.demo.scheduleGrid.ComponentModel;, true, true, true, true, [Lcom.subex.rocforms.sample.client.gwt.demo.scheduleGrid.ComponentModel;/3060182407, 3060182407
```

Can anybody explain what the four flags quoted after the type in each row indicate?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best answer to that, other than poking into the code of course, is reading the Brian Slesinsky's reverse engineering [notes](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1eG0YocsYYbNAtivkLtcaiEE5IOF5u4LUol8-LL0TIKU/edit) about the GWT-RPC format. Have a look under the *policy file format* subsection and you'll find your answer.